# Problems with PHP upload and setting file attributes

Tags: php, html

I am currently trying to add an upload system where a user can upload their own file. They will be able to:

- Name it
- Categorize It
- Add a Description
- Add Instructions for it's use
- Add a thumbnail for it

I have begun by just adding the ability to name it, however I have stumbled at the first stage!

I have very limited knowledge of PHP (I'm a static HTML guy), so I tried to accomplish my goal through the help of others and online tutorials. Find my code sample below.

[Here is a link to the live development site »](http://www.vexnet.org/cubeworld/addamod.html) Hopefully the site will help you to see what I want to do and what goes wrong!

```
if ($_FILES["mod-name"]["error"] > 0)
  {
  echo "Error: " . $_FILES["mod-name"]["error"] . "<br>";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["mod-name"]["name"] . "<br>";
  echo "Type: " . $_FILES["mod-name"]["type"] . "<br>";
  echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["mod-name"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
  echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["mod-name"]["tmp_name"];
  }
?>

<?php
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["mod-name"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((($_FILES["mod-name"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["mod-name"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["mod-name"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["mod-name"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["mod-name"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["mod-name"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["mod-name"]["size"] < 500000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["mod-name"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Error: " . $_FILES["mod-name"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["mod-name"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["mod-name"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["mod-name"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["mod-name"]["tmp_name"];
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
?>

<?php
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["mod-name"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((($_FILES["mod-name"]["type"] == "text/plain"))
&& ($_FILES["mod-name"]["size"] < 20000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["mod-name"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["mod-name"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["mod-name"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["mod-name"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["mod-name"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["mod-name"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

    if (file_exists("/mod/" . $_FILES["mod-name"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["mod-name"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["mod-name"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["mod-name"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "/mod/" . $_FILES["mod-name"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
```

My HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="upload_file.php" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Please fill in every field below!</legend>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="ModName">Mod Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mod-name" placeholder="Enter the mod's name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="ModDesc">Description</label>
            <textarea type="text" class="form-control" id="mod-desc" placeholder="Write a little bit about your mod..." rows="4"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="ModInstall">How to install your Mod:</label>
      <textarea type="text" class="form-control" id="mod-install" placeholder="Help us know how to use your mod!" rows="3"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="ModThumb">Add thumbnail</label>
      <input type="file" id="mod-thumb">
      <p class="help-block">Max file size of image: 300kb</p>
    </div>
    Select the Category(s) that your mod falls under:<br /> 
    <div class="checkbox-inline">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox"> Client Mod
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox-inline">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox"> Game Tweak
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox-inline">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox"> .CUB Model
      </label>
    </div><br />
    <div class="checkbox-inline">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox"> Server Mod
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox-inline">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox"> Web Tool
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox-inline">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox"> Map Editior
      </label>
    </div>
    <hr />

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="ModThumb">Upload your Mod!</label>
      <input type="file" id="mod">
      <p class="help-block">Max file size: 5MB (sorry)</p>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn-lg btn-success">Add it to the Database!</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Just to add, I was creating this by following this tutorial:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: What is wrong? Have you tried fixing it or did you just copy the tutorial here and ask for other people to do your job?

Comment: What is the problem? What is failing?

Comment: I have tried fixing it, I have done everything I can think of. I am stuck now. I have almost no knowledge of PHP, I just cannot afford to hire a PHP dev :( So I am trying to do it myself but it is clear I need help XD!

Comment: The upload fails, it does not put the file in my /mod/ directory. The output:

**Upload: 

Type:
 
Size: 0 kB

Stored in: Invalid file Invalid file**

Comment: The output is telling us that the data was not sent. Put your html form code to see if there is something wrong in there.

Comment: Have you added the enctype="multipart/form-data" bit to your form tag?.

Comment: ^ yes, I am adding my HTML now!

Comment: Added :) Hope that is the stuff you need!

Comment: A bit more... Your file input does not have a "name". You need that. It should go like name="mod-name". Once you send the form try doing some "print_r($_FILES)" in php and send out the results if not working.

Comment: I am sorry, I'm a newb. Could you point me as to where I put this? Thanks!

Comment: similar problem and solution is in this link; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7215789/invalid-file-on-php-file-upload

Comment: <input type="file" name="mod-name">, just below <label for="ModThumb">Upload your Mod!</label>.

Comment: ^^ Tried that, same output :( Also bkilinc - I have no idea where I would put any of that. I am a noob. :(

Comment: Start by simplifying the problem: try this simple form: <form method="post" action="upload_file.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="file" id="mod" name="mod-name">
 <button type="submit" value="Do something" />
</form> And check that it really goes to the upload_file.php file that you made (like doing "echo 'I AM HERE'" at the beginning).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok... I think everything is a bit confusing here. First of, add change your form tag to:

```
<form method="post" action="upload_file.php" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
```

That should allow you to upload files. Then, every single file you upload must have a different name that php would later recognise, so change your file inputs to this:

```
<input type="file" id="mod-thumb" name="thumbnail">
<input type="file" id="mod" name="mod_file">
```

Notice the "name".

Next, go to your upload_file.php... See, every time you go "$_FILES["mod-name"]" you should 
actually go $_FILES["thumbnail"] for the thumbnail file and $_FILES["mod_file"] for the mod file itself. Change the code accordingly.

I just went through your live site and just adding the name tag for a file to "mod-name" gives you output, so file uploading is allowed. Understand that php needs a hook to refer to each file you want to upload and "name" is your hook there.

Comment: Thanks man, I'll try that all out now. I'll go for your comment first :)

Comment: No prob. Just go on trying. You will surely stumble upon directory permissions next - that will happen when everything is ok but you don't have credentials for writing in the destination directory - and some other problems (like how the php keeps checking the same stuff again and again). Just keep asking and learning. Will check back later to see how it goes.

Comment: So I changed all of the parts of the code. I did this with Find and Replace. Would that of worked? I get a Server Error.

Comment: Would you be interested in a trade? If you can help me I can do something for you? This stuff is all really confusing for me! XD

Comment: Surely would not... You need to simplify some bits so you can easily see what's going on. What is that server error?. As said, will check back later. If need be, add your email to your profile so we stop polluting the site with comments until and answer is found. I will reach you.

Comment: The website encountered an error while retrieving http://vexnet.org/cubeworld/upload_file.php. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.
Reload this webpage.
Press the reload button to resubmit the data needed to load the page.
Error code: 500

Comment: I do believe it is working on my simpler version :) Could you test it as well please :D www.vexnet.org/cubeworld/upload_test.html
Use either of the buttons :)

Comment: Oliver: without the php code all that I can see is your client code here. Client code is just a part of the equation: the php code is needed too. Can you update your profile to add your email?. I fear we are polluting the site with much too comments and this can go on for a while.

Comment: I have, anyway here is my email: vextion@aol.com

I was just wondering if you could upload :)